# Calculating heat map weights based on clustering of points

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm, mapkit, heatmap

I have an array of `MKLocationCoordinate2D` in iOS and I'd like to create a heat map of those points based on the clustering of them.

i.e. the more there are in a certain area then the higher the weight.

I've found a load of different frameworks for generating the heat maps and they all require the weights to be calculated yourself (which makes sense).

I'm just not sure where to start with the calculation.

I could do something like calculating the mean distance between each point and every other point but I'm not sure if that's a good idea.

Could someone point me in the direction of how to weight each point based on it's closeness to other points.

Thanks

Comment: You need to gather them into clusters, then you can give these clusters weights. Perhaps this article can help: https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/articles/a-blazingly-fast-open-source-algorithm-for-poi-clustering-on-ios

Comment: @JustAnotherCoder thanks, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by implementing a quad tree and using that to quickly get the number of neighbours within a certain radius.

I can then change the radius to tweak it but it will very quickly return weights based on how many neighbours each point has.